# when it is required that a class will be defined before instantiation?

Tags: php, oop

In the PHP documentation it says:

> Classes should be defined before instantiation (and in some cases this is a requirement).

can some one give me a example of a class that can not be instantiated unless it was previously defined?

Comment: I was not aware of the fact that one can instantiate a class that was NOT defined - except maybe `stdClass`, but this is defined in PHP core. But maybe what's meant here is unserialization of an undefined class which will give you a warning and an incomplete class (`PHP_Incomplete_Class`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (true) {
    new Foo;
    class Foo { }
}
```

The parsing rules are the same as for functions: if they're defined in the "top level" of a file, they're parsed during, well, parsing of the file. If they're defined inside a piece of code which requires runtime evaluation, then the class or function will only be defined when the code is executed, in which case you can't use it before it's been "executed".

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
// Top Level

trait T {
}

$c = new C();

class C {
    use T;
}
```

With trait, this code occurs error (`Class 'C' not found in...`).